# Geckodriver/Marionette driver and Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to use a newer version of firefox with jmeter.webdriver, does anyone have any idea on how to get the Geckodriver working in jmeter WDS tests?

I'm running JMeter 3.0 on windows (though would be executed on jenkins (linux))
Current jmeter FireFox driver doesn't work past firefox 46, and this is really old now, the Geckodriver has been built to replace this from what I can see..

But there doesn't appear to have been any work done to integrate that to jmeter?

Thanks

Comment: could you please post details about your browser, geckodriver, jmeter versions? and other test environment details

Comment: Yeah, even I find the same thing. There is no support yet added for `geckodriver` as of now in 3.1 version. for `chrome`, there is `path to chromedriver` input field present in `jp@gc Chrome Driver Config`. Similar functionality can be provided for `geckodriver`

Comment: Yeah, the chrome driver works fine with the latest version of chrome, but i need to be able to test multiple browsers....grrrr